# Clustering and plotting word vectors - python or R

Tags: python, r, vector, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

So I'm new to python (and to R) and word vectors and been stuck on how to accomplish my next step in learning how to visualize this. While I am trying to work in python, I would be open to applying this to R as well. I'll briefly explain how far I've gotten and where I'm trying to go.

So I have a list of users who receive a list of 10 movies associated to that user. I've managed to get the list, create an output csv file and matched up user attributes like gender, age, location, etc. I've extracted and created attributes for the movies as well like genre and year made.

But next, I'm trying to cluster the user to see how similar the list of movies are to each user. The way I've done this, is I've extracted  the genres of each movie and put them in a list. So a user who has a list of say user 1 'comedy', drama', romantic comedy' would be similar to another user 2 who likes comedy, romance, but not similar to user 3 who likes 'horror', 'crime','thriller'. I'm imagining about 5-6 clusters based on these genres (so like a 'Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Family', 'Horror'.) If I plot that, I'd see like to see a cluster of user 1 and 2 in one cluster (around the Comedy cluster), user 3 in another (close to the horror cluster), and so on. Then I could color the plots according to age, gender, etc to see do the same age groups like similar movies, or will i see more males closer to the "Action" movie cluster and more females towards "romance"?

And that's where I'm stuck. I've looked into sckit to try to graph this but just don't know where to go with it. The lists are of different lengths too and I've been able to get the cosine similarities of the users compared to the other users. I've managed to create a dataframe of user number and the list of genres in a second column. I've managed to create a csv file with the user and the genres separated to be in their own column. How do I take this information now and cluster or plot this in a vector space? Below is the dataframe I've been able to construct and used for the calculating cosine similarity between different users.

```
    ID  Genre
0   1   ['Adventure', ""Children's"", 'Drama', 'Comedy', 'Musical', 'Horror', 'Drama', 'Drama', 'Mystery', 'Documentary', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Drama', 'Comedy', 'Romance']"
1   2   ['Horror', 'Mystery', 'Thriller', 'Documentary', 'Action', 'Comedy', 'Musical', 'Sci-Fi', 'Horror', 'Sci-Fi', 'Thriller', 'Adventure', 'Animation', ""Children's"", 'Musical', 'Romance', 'Documentary', 'Action', 'Adventure', 'Western', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Comedy']"
2   3   ['Documentary', 'Drama', 'Thriller', 'Documentary', 'Comedy', 'Horror', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Documentary', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Action', 'Adventure', 'Sci-Fi', 'War', 'Drama']
3   4   ['Drama', 'War', 'Drama', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Action', 'Thriller', 'Comedy', 'Horror', 'Horror', 'Comedy', 'Musical', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Comedy', 'Horror']
4   5   ['Documentary', 'Drama', 'Documentary', 'Comedy', 'Romance', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Animation', ""Children's"", 'Action', 'Drama', 'Drama', 'Comedy', 'Romance']"
5   6   ['Horror', 'Documentary', 'Comedy', 'Horror', 'Drama', 'Drama', 'Drama', 'Action', 'Comedy', 'Comedy', 'Horror']
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you really want to do but if sentiment analysis is your goal I would advice you to do this.

```
a = ['Horror', 'Mystery', 'Thriller', 'Documentary', 'Action', 'Comedy', 'Musical', 'Sci-Fi', 'Horror', 'Sci-Fi', 'Thriller', 'Adventure', 'Animation', 'Musical', 'Romance', 'Documentary', 'Action', 'Adventure', 'Western', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Comedy']

>>> b= set(a)

>>> b
{'Action', 'Romance', 'Documentary', 'Sci-Fi', 'Adventure', 'Musical', 'Animation', 'Thriller', 'Western', 'Drama', 'Comedy', 'Horror', 'Mystery'}
```

You can now convert movie genre to numerical values,e.g

```
'Action' = 1
```

After that you can cluster the data,but choice of algorithm is not so simple.You can use k-means,fuzzy c means or some of plenty of other algorithms.You can read more about this [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7522583/)